# Unable to post link to CloudApp that uses a short URL without an available expanded URL format

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

I tried to post a question today that includes a link to a sample project uploaded to [CloudApp](https://www.getcloudapp.com). When I went to post, I got an error message stating I can't use a URL shortener. Okay, this service does indeed generate a URL that is short. The problem is this is the only URL they provide - visiting the URL doesn't expand to a longer/permanent URL. I ultimately had to figure out how to link to the file itself hosted directly on Amazon, bypassing CloudApp altogether. I did some research and found [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts) that explains the blacklist, and one should report any problems found, so that is what I am here to do. The format this service uses is `http :// cl.ly / ############`.

[image]